# splitting and matching values from string

Tags: c#

Alright, you guys have been amazing to me in the past and I can't thank you all enough. I'm working on a program to help people playing ARK: Survival Evolved to manage their dedicated servers.

Within the .map file there are two string values that we will be focusing on for right now; TamerName, which is the name of the user who tamed the dinosaur, and then there is the DinoName, which as you can guess is the dinosaur's name.

The strings are not set up in a way that you can simply search for instance of TamerName and then list the Dino's under that one user, instead they are listed throughout the file itself. What I want to do is have a TabControl which creates individual tabs named after the user, then inside that Tab populate a Panel with the Dinosaurs tamed by that user.

The file always stores information like
TamerName
     -DinoName

so it can look like this (as an example)

Brandon
     -Derp
Katie
     -Derpette
Brandon
     -Derp2
Brandon
     -Derp3
Katie
     -Derpette2

and so on. I want it to list like this

Tab1(TabName = Brandon)
     -Derp
     -Derp2
     -Derp3
Tab2(TabName = Katie)
     -Derpette
     -Derpette2

and so on.

I currently have a method designed to dump results to a List as Name-Dino

and I can provide the code for that if needed. Hopefully I explained that all properly!!!

Comment: Yes, it would help if you could provide the code for dumping the results so I could focus only on getting the TabControl function implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have a List which is formatted like "Name-Dino", one way to do this would be to create a new array or list of the Tamers. In this example `listOfNamesAndDinos` is your already existing list.

```
List<string> tamerList = new List<string>();

foreach(string tamerDino in listOfNamesAndDinos)
{
    string tamerName = tamerDino.Split("-")[0].Trim();
    if(!tamerList.Contains(tamerName))
    {
        tamerList.Add(tamerName);
    }
}

//Create tabs using each name from list of tamers

foreach(string tamer in tamerList)
{
    List<string> fullDinosForTamer = listOfNamesAndDinos.Where(e => e.StartsWith(tamer)).ToList();
    //Populate your panel with the newly found dinos
}
```

**This method will require you to have** `using System.Linq`  **in your namespace declarations**

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to @Alfie Goodacre who gave me the foundation to figuring this out :) I had to tweak the code a bit, which I have provided below. If anyone can think of a better, more compact way of writing this I'm open to suggestions! Thank you!!

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ark = new OpenFileDialog();
        ark.Filter = "ARK Map (*.ark)|*.ark";
        int p = 0;
        if (ark.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            List<string> findings = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                findings.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", Tamed_Dino(ark.FileName, Dino_Tamer, 37)[i], Tamed_Dino(ark.FileName, Dino_Name, 35)[i]));

            }
            List<string> tamerList = new List<string>();

            foreach (string tamerDino in findings)
            {
                string tamerName = tamerDino.Split('-')[0].Trim();
                if (!tamerList.Contains(tamerName))
                {
                    tamerList.Add(tamerName);
                    Console.WriteLine(tamerName);
                }
            }
            for (int l = 0; l < tamerList.Count; l++)
            {
                string title = tamerList[l];
                TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(title);
                multi_prof.TabPages.Add(title);
                Panel np = new Panel();
                np.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                np.Location = new Point(10, 10);
                np.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                np.Name = tamerList[l];
                multi_prof.SelectedIndex = l;
                multi_prof.SelectedTab.Invoke((Action)(() => multi_prof.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(np)));

                foreach (string tamer in tamerList)
                {
                    List<string> fullDinosForTamer = findings.Where(r => r.StartsWith(tamer)).ToList();
                    //Populate your panel with the newly found dinos
                    Label lbl;
                    p = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < fullDinosForTamer.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (fullDinosForTamer[i].StartsWith(tamerList[l]))
                        {
                            lbl = new Label();
                            lbl.Text = fullDinosForTamer[i].Split('-')[1];
                            lbl.Name = fullDinosForTamer[i];
                            lbl.AutoSize = true;
                            lbl.Location = new Point(10, p * 20);
                            np.Invoke((Action)(() => np.Controls.Add(lbl)));
                            p++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```